# AspNetCore ModelState type missing in one specific context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a Controller action in my Asp Net Core (2.2) project. 
I have declared

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
```

Action code is as follows:

```
    1:   public IActionResult Index()
    2:   {
    3:       var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
    4:       foreach ( ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
    ...
```

For some reason, the compiler is highlighting line 4 with a message

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ModelState' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ics-billing C:\Users...\Controllers\HomeController.cs  30  Active

I don't understand how the compiler is unable to resolve the type 'ModelState' on line 4, whereas it has no problem with exactly the same class being referenced on line 3?

Comment: Is your controller inherited: `Controller` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ModelState` on line three is a property of the `ControllerBase` class, which is what `Controller` inherits from. On line four, it's looking for a type named `ModelState` but that type doesn't exist. The `ModelState` property is of type `ModelStateDictionary`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.modelstate?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_ModelState

And the `Values` property of `ModelStateDictionary` is of type `ValueEnumerable`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary.values?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ModelBinding_ModelStateDictionary_Values

Which is an `IEnumerable` of `ModelStateEntry`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary.valueenumerable?view=aspnetcore-3.0

I believe you need to change `ModelState modelState` on line four to `ModelStateEntry modelStateEntry`. However, you can also use `var` instead of specifying the type name.

Comment: Really appreciate for such informational links plus thinking how stupid I was that didn't even try solution for using var.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop for ModelState errors by this code:

```
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values
                                    .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                    .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));                    
                return View(model);
            }
```